# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with legal index , java, imagej

Tags: java, imagej

I am currently trying to get my head wrapped around imagej, and just trying to duplicate an image and spit out the output. The general idea is to get the image, get the pixel array off the image processor, copy it into a new array, and build up a new image from that array.

Now in this, the value of aPixels_org[0] exists, as you can see by the console output. but its still throwing an arrayoutofbounds exception, even with all my checks.

Here is the code...  (btw  l. is just an logger object, and just a sanity check to check if the array values exist in the if condition below. Do advise if there is a better way, as i am a c++ guy, and am used to checking stuff directly, as java wont allow the if(int){} check)

I am getting the aPixels_org from a function, an dthe aPixels_dup is just created as such

```
int[] aPixels_dup = new int[iWidth*iHeight];
```

where iWidth*iHeight is the size of the array needed. I have also tried to generate the size directly with the array.length() option.
The problem code is

```
System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>." + aPixels_dup[0] +"  " + aPixels_org[0] + "  " + iWidth + "  " + iHeight);
    if(Integer.toString(aPixels_org[0]) != null &&  Integer.toString(aPixels_dup[0]) != null )
    {
        l.info("Arrays exsist");
        System.arraycopy(aPixels_org,0,aPixels_dup,0,iWidth*iHeight);
        l.info("Array Copied");
    }
    else{l.warn("Something is NULL");}
    l.info("");
```

This is the error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at Alpha_.DuplicateCurrentImage(Alpha_.java:64)
at Alpha_.run(Alpha_.java:81)
at ij.IJ.runUserPlugIn(IJ.java:185)
at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:152)
at ij.Executer.runCommand(Executer.java:127)
at ij.Executer.run(Executer.java:64)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Here is the console output

```
[INFO] % FILE: Alpha_.java % CLASS: Alpha_ % FUNCTION: DuplicateCurrentImage % LINE: 59    % COMMENT: OK % % % TIMESTAMP: 2013-01-17 00:26:55,942
 0  -1393202  466  466
[INFO] % FILE: Alpha_.java % CLASS: Alpha_ % FUNCTION: DuplicateCurrentImage % LINE: 63 % COMMENT: Arrays exsist % % % TIMESTAMP: 2013-01-17 00:26:55,942
```

Thats the end of my output, and the program crashes with the above error. As you can see, all the 4 values exist in some form or the other. I googled the error and found that the error is

> > > Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Am i missing something obvious here?

RE

Comment: It's a good excercise to allow you to do more complicated things but if all you want to do is create a copy of the image call 'ImageProcessor.duplicate()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both arrays—`aPixels_org` and `aPixels_dup`—must have length at least `iWidth*iHeight` (which is 217156, according to your console output). One (or both) of the arrays must be shorter that that, which is why you are getting the exception. Also be sure that the value of `iWidth*iHeight` did not increase between the allocation of `aPixels_dup` and the call to `System.arraycopy`.

It would be safer to use `Math.min(aPixels_org.length, aPixels_dup.length)` as the last argument to `System.arraycopy`. However, that would hide any length errors in your code. You might want to `assert` that both arrays have the expected length.

Also, your checks seem to be meaningless. The fact that an element at index 0 exists in both arrays is kind of irrelevant. Also, `Integer.toString(int)` never returns `null`. Here's a version of your code that does some sensible checks:

```
if (aPixels_org != null &&
    aPixels_dup != null &&
    aPixels_org.length == aPixels_dup.length &&
    aPixels_org.length == iWidth*iHeight )
{
    l.info("Array sizes match");
    System.arraycopy(aPixels_org,0,aPixels_dup,0,iWidth*iHeight);
    l.info("Array Copied");
}
else{l.warn("Something is NULL or dimensions are off");}
l.info("");
```

Comment: Dup is allocated - must the the source array is too short

Comment: @Bohemian - unless the value of `iWidth` or `iHeight` went up between the allocation and the call to `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: Does the image have a number of frames? If so you should have iWidth*iHeight*iNoOfFrames for the array length

Comment: @medPhys-pl - Good point. Actually, for the purpose of copying the data, it would be enough to just use the array lengths, ignoring the values of `iWidth` and `iHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). *I **highlighted** the reason I think is the cause for your error.*

```
 public static void arraycopy(Object src,
             int srcPos,
             Object dest,
             int destPos,
             int length)
 ...
```

Otherwise, if any of the following is true, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown and the destination is not modified:

- The `srcPos` argument is negative.
- The `destPos` argument is negative.
- The `length` argument is negative.
- **`srcPos+length` is greater than `src.length`, the length of the source array.**
- `destPos+length` is greater than `dest.length`, the length of the destination array.